# Connect to multiple databases in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, connection, pyqt5, qsqldatabase

I need to connect to two different databases and servers. Right now I can only connect to one database using this code:

```
def createConnection()
    global db
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
    db.setDatabaseName('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWS=%s;' % (SERVER1, DATABASE1, USERNAME1, PASSWORD1))
    if db.open():
        print("connected")
        return True
    else:
        print("failed")
        return False
```

Then somewhere in my code I call something like this:

```
if createConnection():
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_name")
    qry.exec()
    while qry.next()
        col1 = qry.value("column1")
        col2 = qry.value("column2")
```

Now, I have to connect also to another database that is different: `SERVER2, DATABASE2, USERNAME2, PASSWORD2`. How can I do that?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, please explain why so that I can try to improve it.

Comment: I don't but the error keeps happening about addDatabase, I've done some research and I'm ended up using pyodbc now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not create function who takes variables.

```
def createConnection(SERVER, DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    global db
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
    db.setDatabaseName('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWS=%s;' % (SERVER, DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    if db.open():
        print("connected")
        return True
    else:
        print("failed")
        return False
```

while calling provide those variables.

```
if createConnection(SERVER1, DATABASE1, USERNAME1, PASSWORD1):
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_name")
    qry.exec()
    while qry.next()
        col1 = qry.value("column1")
        col2 = qry.value("column2")
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns an error saying
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work
and QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed

Comment: @kokoro i guess you need to close the db connection once your work is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple connections, you must give each one a unique name. If no name is supplied, the default connection will be used, and any previous connection will be removed.

So you need to do something like this:

```
def createConnection(conn, server, dbase, user, pwd)
    if QSqlDatabase.contains(conn):
        QSqlDatabase.removeDatabase(conn)
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC', conn)
    db.setDatabaseName('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWS=%s;' % (server, dbase, user, pwd))
    if db.open():
        print("connected")
        return True
    else:
        print("failed")
        return False
```

and then do:

```
CONN1 = 'conn_01'
CONN2 = 'conn_02'
...

if createConnection(CONN1, SERVER1, DATABASE1, USERNAME1, PASSWORD1):
    qry = QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase.database(CONN1))
    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_name")
    qry.exec()
    while qry.next()
        col1 = qry.value("column1")
        col2 = qry.value("column2")
```